# undefined method error on local server where method works on live server-Why is the new code breaking it?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to integrate our app with MailChimp, so that new users get added to our mailing list and new paid subscribers get updated on the mailing list as paid subscribers (we have a MERGE VARS for that). In order to test that the list is updating properly when the customer pays for a subscription, I'm trying to run the code with the test server for Stripe. (I inherited the code after we had tested it, so I haven't done this before.)

I'm running into an undefined method error, and I can't figure out where it's coming from, since it is working just fine on the live site, and I haven't changed that part of the code.

in the initializer file stripe.rb, I changed `Stripe.api_key
="the live secret key"` to the test secret key, just subbing in the other key.

I did the same in our layout/application.html.erb file (where we put the initial call to Stripe per Stripe's instructions), swapping out the public live key for the public test key.

In the account_controller processing method (which is called for payment processing on the Stripe token and updating our server with the type of subscription.):

```
def processing
  begin
  if params[:coupon][0] != "_"
    @coupon = params[:coupon]
  else
    @coupon = nil
  end
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :email => current_user.email,
  :card  => params[:stripeToken],
  :plan => params[:plan],
  :coupon => @coupon
  )

  current_user.subscription = params[:plan]
  current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
  current_user.canceled = false
  current_user.save!

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
  end
  #only this code is new, from here:
  #for gibbon updating subscription status
  gb=Gibbon::API.new
  email=current_user.email
  subscription=user.subscription
  updated_date=user.updated_at.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
  gb.lists.subscribe({:id => "our list id", :email => {:email => "#{email}"}, :merge_vars => {:SUB => "test", :UPDATE => "#{updated_date}"}, :update_existing=>true , :double_optin => false, :send_welcome=> false})
  #to here is new code

  current_user

  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to account_confirmation_path }
  end
 end
```

I'm getting a "NoMethodError in AccountController#processing

undefined method 'canceled=' for #User:an-id-here" (note the #User: an id here is in pointy brackets, but those aren't showing up here.)
error. This code works on the live site, so that makes me think it must be something I've done here. Canceled is a column on our User model, which is a boolean indicating whether they've canceled. It is not set as attr_accesible or attr_accessor, but as I said, that code hasn't changed and works on the live site.

I'm not sure what the problem is and I feel like I don't have enough information to start figuring it out. The server is only recording the same error message as shows up in the browser. (Oh, and I'm running the test code only on my local server, not the live server).

What might be causing the undefined method error? I'm not seeing anything in the code I changed that should do it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `canceled` column in your development database?

Comment: Is it possible you have `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false` specified in the production.rb under config/environments but not in the development.rb ?

Comment: @muistooshort, you're right, I don't. I had changed the column in my database, migrated, then tried to rollback but before I really knew what I was doing, and so left the columns in my database. Turns out the columns in my local database are a mess, because I didn't know what I was doing at first. I'm going to have to recreate the database.